# Is proof-of-stake a viable alternative / augmentation to proof-of-work?

Tags: protocol, blockchain, future-proof

Meni mentioned [Proof of Stake](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3123/78) as a possible way to augment Proof of Work as the underlying mechanism powering Bitcoin confirmations.

Is it viable? What are its downsides? Who has analyzed it? (I don't see a lot of people on [this thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=37194.0))

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[This answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3129/78) might be enough to make proof-of-stake not needed.

Comment: Your question is a good question, but this is not an answer to this question. Again, please do not move random discussions which are not backed up with some solid theory to this site (Especially using two levels of redirection).

Comment: I did mean it as an answer. If proof of stake is not needed (as I currently believe might be the case), then the whole viability question is moot.